# Brainstorm idea to overcome Heroku's 30s timeout and HTMLUnit's slow page rendering

Tags: java, heroku, htmlunit

I've got a strange issue.

I am doing some screen scraping and then presenting data back to my user to make some selections. I don't have any control over the sites I am working with and I need them to first execute their Javascript.

The process is working fine locally, it just takes up to a minute for everything to happen. But when I push to Heroku the request times out after 30s, although I can see through the logs, that the actual processing keeps happening.

Could you recommend one of these solutions, or some alternative:

1. Somehow increase Heroku's timeout - I believe this is not possible (I am using PlayFramework 1.2.7 and Java)
2. Somehow speed up HTMLUnit - I've pasted my code below
3. Get the page HTML a different way - all I need is the HTML - after the Javscript (Ajax) has executed. Is there a better/faster way to do this?
4. Do the work in two steps, first use HTMLUnit to grab the page code and save it to a DB. Then grab the page code from the DB and do some processing on it. This is all I can think of.

The code:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);

Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
String html = response.getContentAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to run long-running processes is to use asynchronous workers. Even a process that takes 5 seconds will lock your web worker for that amount of time (assuming you're running synchronous workers), so it's always wise to delegate such tasks to asynchronous workers.

Follow this guide to get started: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/asynchronous-web-worker-model-using-rabbitmq-in-java